# ios app crash on start (ImageLoaderMachOcompressed:: rebase) in device

Tags: ios, crash, gstreamer, dyld

I build my custom framework with Gstreamer, and test it in my sample project. It works well in the simulator, but strange crashes on start in the device.

It crashes before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, just show the message as below.[image]

[image]

so, I open the Dyld Log, try to figure out what the root cause is.

a. In device, it stops at XPCKit
[image]

b. In simulator, it works fine, and starts the next step "_dyld_register_func_for_add_image(0x5beec9b)"
[image]

I don't know why my app stops at loading XPCkit Framework. Is there any hint for next??

Comment: Finally, I found the root cause is from Gstreamer framework. when I wrap the Gstreamer framework to my custom framework.

Comment: Finally, I found the root cause is from Gstreamer framework. when I wrap the Gstreamer framework to my custom framework, there is a defined about "GST_PLUGIN_STATIC_REGISTER(x264)" in gst_ios_init.m. If I register this plugin, then my app will crash as my question. I don't know why, but it does work well while removing the plugin.